# Transition animation is not working on landscape mode

Tags: android, screen-orientation, android-transitions, overridependingtransition

I'm trying to animate transitions between Activities in my application. I have **right_to_left.xml** which is working on **Portrait** screen orientation.

Here is **right_to_left.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime"
    android:fromXDelta="100%"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
    android:toXDelta="0" />
</set>
```

Here is **right_to_left_slide_out.xml** (to slide out previous activity on transition.)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime"
    android:fromXDelta="0"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
    android:toXDelta="-100%p" />
</set>
```

I was using it after **startActivity()** and there was no problem on **Portrait** mode.

But I added an option to change screen orientation to **Landscape** mode.

If landscape mode is enabled, I set requested orientation with code below in **onCreate()**.

```
//SCREEN ORIENTATION
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
```

This works well, activity is created in Landscape mode without any issue.
But when I try to start activity with **overridePendingTransition(R.anim.right_to_left, R.anim.right_to_left_slide_out)** which is working on Portrait mode, no  transition animation seems on Landscape mode.

Is there something I've missed?

**EDIT:**
I've tried to create a new animation xml file that works with YDelta. It didn't work either.

Comment: add `android:configChanges="orientation"` for your activity in manifest

Answer (score 1):

The animation is not playing because android studio doesn't render views that are not set to Visible or Invisible when the app starts. The problem is that your landscape view is not already rendered when the animation starts playing. It renders it on the spot and skips the animation entirely.

To test this theory, simply add to your activity a version of your landscape layout with < include > and set it to invisible. Then run the app. See if the animation plays. If it does, then this theory is correct and we can try to figure out a solution.

Good luck.